# granting access for remote account to local database instance

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

i have two computers in a same domain, there is database instance on one of them, which is the DC, the question how can i add an account (reside on the other computer) to grant access to that DB!. i tried to add the account in login window but it didn't work! it is even not listed.
these screenshots will help:
[image: screen1]
[image: screen2]

Comment: Not that you should include this in screen shot form, but it looks like you're trying to use an account from the local machine (`WIN2016\Administrator`), which may or may not exist. First, make sure you're using an account that exists - a domain account, since you want to be able to connect from a different account. Make sure your account can successfully log into the remote computer. Then add it as a login on SQL Server. If you have an actual DBA, you might ask them to help you find the right info.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to create an AD service account on your SQL server. Then also make sure that AD service account is on application server, and is you local admin group on that box (I'm guessing on this part).

1. Create the AD Service account
2. Add the newly created AD account to your SQL Server, but wait a bit for the AD account to propagate. Give it a minute or five.
3. Create a new SQL login, keep Windows Auth selected, and click the Search... button
4. When the Select User or Group window appears, click the Locations... button
    *If you are wanting to add a group, then you will want to click the Objects Type button, and select the Groups checkbox before you search*
   [image]
5. On the Locations window select Entire Directory, and click OK
   [image]
   [image]
6. Enter in the user name you just created, and click the Check Names button. If it finds the user you will know, and click the OK button
7. Now, assign it to a server role, or assign it a database with the permissions needed for your application.

Now try to connect your application server to your SQL Server.

Now, you can cheat. However, I wouldn't recommend this, but if you don't really care who is making the call from your application server. Run this script below. Change the domain to your domain, and replace SERVERNAME with the name of your server. Once this created on the SQL server give it perms to the server or database in question.

```
 CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\SERVERNAME$] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
```